# Exporting / Migrating out a Drupal database "correctly" via "new version" of PHPMyAdmin

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7, phpmyadmin

I've made a screenshot of my settings; do I have all of this right if I intend on migrating it back to Drupal on a separate server? I plan to import it again through SSH most preferably but may also use PHPMyAdmin.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

If you have ssh access, I highly recommend to use mysqldump command to export and then use mysql command to import. I have bad experiences of using phpmyadmin to export and import drupal db (e.g timeout issue). also note that mysqldump/mysql is a lot more faster.

Export:

```
mysqldump -u=xxx -p=xxx mydb > dump.sql
```

Import:

```
mysql -u=xxx -p=xxx mydb < dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to uncheck `AUTO_INCREMENT` below CREATE `enter code here`TABLE options, and check the `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using the [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module from Drupal which may make it easier for you than doing it yourself through phpmyadmin.

> Backup and Migrate simplifies the task of backing up and restoring
>   your Drupal database or copying your database from one Drupal site to
>   another. It supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as
>   automatic scheduled backups.
>
> With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database
>   tables to a file download or save to a file on the server, and to
>   restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You can
>   chose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded
>   by default.